# VBA Combine Multiple columns of data into 1 column

Tags: vba, excel

I am still newer to VBA and have been trying everything I can think of to get this accomplished before asking for help, but cannot figure it out.

I have an excel file with multiple tabs. I am only concerned with 2 of them. I need to combine rows based off of their values not being blank from tab "Roadmap" into column B on tab "PPPP". The code I have will do that for the first set of data, but then replaces that data with the second set.

```
Sub Move_PPPP()

Sheets("PPPP").Select
Rows("2:1000").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Dim rowCount2 As Long, shtSrc As Worksheet
Dim shtDest As Worksheet
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim currentRow As Long

    Set shtSrc = Sheets("Roadmap")
    Set shtDest = Sheets("PPPP")

    rowCount2 = shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng2 = shtSrc.Range("C6:C" & rowCount2)

    currentRow = 2

        For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
        If cell2.Value <> "" Then

       shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2 = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 10).Text
       shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2 = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 11).Text
       shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2 = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 12).Text
          currentRow = currentRow + 1

        ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then

        End If
        Next cell2

End Sub
```

I have tried to add a range for my destination sheet, but doing that is only giving me 9 rows of the last row of data from tab "Roadmap"

```
Sub Move_PPPP()

Sheets("PPPP").Select
Rows("2:1000").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Dim rowCount2 As Long, shtSrc As Worksheet
Dim columnCount As Long
Dim shtDest As Worksheet
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim currentRow As Long

    Set shtSrc = Sheets("Roadmap")
    Set shtDest = Sheets("PPPP")

    rowCount2 = shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    columnCount = shtDest.Cells(Columns.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng2 = shtSrc.Range("C6:C" & rowCount2)
    Set rng = shtDest.Range("B2:B" & columnCount & currentRow)

    currentRow = 2

        For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
        If cell2.Value <> "" Then

        rng.Value = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 10).Text

            currentRow = currentRow + 1

        ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then

        End If
        Next cell2


End Sub
```

Sample Data

Roadmap Tab

Column: C         D      E       F      G      H     I    J    K       L       M
Headers: Project   Status  Open  Closed  Name   P1    P2  P3   P4      P5       P6

Row 1: FISMA      New    Yes    No     Albert  na    na  na   na   New Day  Old Data
Row 2: QRD       Closed   No    Yes    Albert  na   na  na   na     na     Closed

Desired Outcome. Combine Column C with Column M when M <> blank, loop through entire row and put that data in column B of PPPP tab. Then combine column C with N when N <> blank and put that on PPPP tab, column B under the data from column M.

PPPP Tab

Cell B2
FISMA - New Day

Cell B4
FISMA - Old Data
QRD - Closed

SOLUTION:

```
Sub Move_PPPP()

Sheets("PPPP").Select
Rows("2:1000").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Dim rowCount2 As Long, shtSrc As Worksheet
Dim shtDest As Worksheet
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim currentRow As Long

    Set shtSrc = Sheets("Roadmap")
    Set shtDest = Sheets("PPPP")

    rowCount2 = shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng2 = shtSrc.Range("C6:C" & rowCount2)

    currentRow = shtDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
        If cell2.Value2 <> "" Then
        shtDest.Range("A" & currentRow).Value2 = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 9).Text
        currentRow = currentRow + 1

        ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then

        End If
        Next cell2

    Set rng2 = shtSrc.Range("C6:C" & rowCount2)

    currentRow = shtDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

       For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
       If cell2.Value2 <> ""  Then
       shtDest.Range("A" & currentRow + 1).Value2 = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 10).Text
       currentRow = currentRow + 1

        ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then

        End If
        Next cell2

    Set rng2 = shtSrc.Range("C6:C" & rowCount2)

    currentRow = shtDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

       For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
       If cell2.Value2 <> ""  Then
       shtDest.Range("A" & currentRow + 1).Value2 = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 11).Text
       currentRow = currentRow + 1

        ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then

        End If
        Next cell2

            Set rng2 = shtSrc.Range("C6:C" & rowCount2)

    currentRow = shtDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

       For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
       If cell2.Value2 <> ""  Then
       shtDest.Range("A" & currentRow + 1).Value2 = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 12).Text
       currentRow = currentRow + 1

        ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then

        End If
        Next cell2
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first version, try this :

```
 Sub Move_PPPP()

Sheets("PPPP").Select
Rows("2:1000").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Dim rowCount2 As Long, shtSrc As Worksheet
Dim shtDest As Worksheet
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim currentRow As Long

    Set shtSrc = Sheets("Roadmap")
    Set shtDest = Sheets("PPPP")

    rowCount2 = shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng2 = shtSrc.Range("C6:C" & rowCount2)

    currentRow = shtDest.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
        If cell2.Value <> "" Then

       shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2 = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 10).Text
       shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow + 1).Value2 = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 11).Text
       shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow + 2).Value2 = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 12).Text
          currentRow = currentRow + 1

        ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then

        End If
        Next cell2

 Set rng2 = shtSrc.Range("D6:D" & rowCount2)

    currentRow = shtDest.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
        If cell2.Value <> "" Then

       shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2 = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 10).Text
       shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow + 1).Value2 = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 11).Text
       shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow + 2).Value2 = "           " & cell2.Text & " - " & cell2.Offset(0, 12).Text
          currentRow = currentRow + 1

        ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then

        End If
        Next cell2

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that is giving me the same out put as before. It replaces the data with each offset. I need it to skip a row and place the next set of data under it. @R3uK

Comment: Ok, but in the first one, you write 3 times in the same cell `shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2 =` , so here is the main problem! Do you want them to be stack horizontaly or verticaly?

Comment: I want them vertical in column B on tab PPPP, not overlapping. I want the information from tab Roadmap column L to populate on tab PPPP column B row 2 - however many rows of data there is, and then Roadmap column M to populate on PPPP 1 cell under where column L data was just moved. @R3uK

Comment: OK it's far more clearer, I'm on my phone but I'll try to edit consequently. Just your 3 different (as said in the previous comment) info are still normal?

Comment: Thank you! I did not think I could keep adding the For Each / If statements. I was able to use what you gave a put it into my code to get what I needed. I really appreciate your help!! @R3uK